# Removing "microsoft" from B2C login page URL

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We are using Azure AD B2C login page.
The login page URL looks something like this: https://myb2ctenant.b2clogin.com/myb2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/...

What we would like to achieve is to remove the "onmicrosoft" part from the url. 
We would not like the users to see microsoft on our page.

For instance such an URL would be OK: https://myb2ctenant.b2clogin.com/b0d3b723-cde6-455d-bc94-ba268d2195e0/oauth2/v2.0/...

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, instead of the tenant name, you can use tenant guid / objectId.

Also you should move to b2clogin url. The URL format described by you is being deprecated. By using you can completely get rid of Microsoft in the url.

Please read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/b2clogin

Comment: Sorry, I wrote wrong host. I am already using b2c login url. I edited my original question. My I tried writing the Subscription ID in the URL but I got a 404 response for the URL. Where do I get a tenant guid or object id which would work?

Comment: Go to Azure AD blade inside your Azure AD B2C directory, go to Properties, you'll find the Tenant ID GUID there.

Comment: you can also use well-known endpoint. https://login.windows.net/yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com/.well-known/openid-configuration